# Calculate distance in a configuration with right angles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

In the following figure, it is given three right angles and distances :

$ED = 3 $ , $ EB = 7$ and $CE = 5$.

Is it possible to calculate the length $EA$.

I tried using cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ and angles but couldn't find the expression.

thanks for any ideas.
[image]

Comment: Is BED a straight line?

Comment: yes BED is straight

Comment: Draw a line the passes through point E and is perpendicular to CB, then you have two similar triangles EAB and EFB where F is the point that crosses CB.

Comment: without additional information, it might not be possible. If ADB or ABE is equilateral, then we can find. CE = 5 and BE = 7? The diagram is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Use the coordinate system. Let $E=(0,0)$, $C = (0,5)$, $B= (-7,0)$ and $D=(3,0)$.

Now you have to calculate $A$ which is in the intersection of lines $AB$ and $AD$ (perpendiculars to $BC$ and $DC$).

Answer (score 1):

I'll solve it trigonometrically using essential concepts like The Law of sines and cosines.
EA=5.8 See the link Below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-OAlQzpJwEDPF7iwhxW575xLe-YbjR5L/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please type your solution into the body of your answer. Links may break (and people may be reluctant to click through to random files on the internet).

Comment: The problem is I can't write in the site and when I saw how,I concluded that I must memorise some symbols,which I found hard. Can you please guide me?